# Can not unhide a row, are there different ways to hide rows in google spread sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets, for a client. There are some rows hidden.
I can not unhide them. If I hide some rows myself, then I get a little updown arrow, that I can click to unhide them. However this is not present on the ones that are already hidden.

Is there another way that they could be hidden, that I can investigate?

Comment: Are you using Excel also, or just Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: @music2myear I am not using Excel, gnumeric, kspread, libreoffice calc, star office, lotus 123, … just google sheets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was filters. I turned them off.

Go to Menu → Data → filters, you can turn them off, you may want to adjust them some other way.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar, but different, problem: I had narrowed the column to the point where I could not see anything in the column and I could not grab it and make it wider. (hope this is useful for people that search for this.)

## Solution:

Highlight the column to the left or right of the column you can not see the data in, then highlight the column you can not see the data in and then right click and Resize.

Now you can see both columns.  This only took me 30 minutes to figure out, hope it helps.